# How to setup a key in org-agenda to mark a task as DONE and then ARCHIVE it?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, key-bindings

How can one setup a key in org-agenda to mark a task as DONE and then ARCHIVE it?

In my org-agenda, I have a key to mark as done (courtesy to Sacha Chua):

```
(defun sacha/org-agenda-done (&optional arg)
  "Mark current TODO as done.
This changes the line at point, all other lines in the agenda referring to
the same tree node, and the headline of the tree node in the Org-mode file."
  (interactive "P")
  (org-agenda-todo "DONE"))
;; Override the key definition for org-exit
(define-key org-agenda-mode-map "x" 'sacha/org-agenda-done)
```

I have a key to archive an entry (in the archive file while keeping context, courtesy of @codefalling in https://gist.github.com/CodeFalling/87b116291aa87fde72cb):

```
(define-key org-agenda-mode-map "z" 'org-agenda-archive)
```

But when I tried to combine both into a single key, I partially failed, because emacs does not return back to the original buffer in org-agenda mode after archiving the entry:

```
(defun jyby/org-agenda-mark-done-and-archive ()
"Mark the current TODO as done and archive it."
(interactive)
(org-agenda-todo "DONE")
(save-excursion
  (org-agenda-switch-to)
  (org-archive-subtree-hierarchical)
  )
)
(define-key org-agenda-mode-map "D" 'jyby/org-agenda-mark-done-and-archive)
```

**Any idea why?**

(For the record, I did try with the function save-current-buffer, to no avail.)

OF course, I would also like to cancel and archive in a single key:

```
(defun jyby/org-agenda-cancel-and-archive ()
    "Mark the current TODO as done and archive it."
    (interactive)
    (save-current-buffer
      (org-agenda-todo "CANC")
      (org-agenda-switch-to)
      (org-archive-subtree-hierarchical)
      )
    )
(define-key org-agenda-mode-map "C" 'jyby/org-agenda-cancel-and-archive)
```